# How to read a csv file partially in node.js

Tags: node.js, csv

I have a large csv file and I want to read to only read the file partially, lets say the first 1000 rows.

I am planning to use either [fast-csv](https://github.com/C2FO/fast-csv) package or [node-csv-parse](https://github.com/wdavidw/node-csv-parse).

The task is not as simple as reading 1000 lines as a row could have a multi-line value.

Could some help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code below worked for me, using the [node-csv-parse](https://github.com/wdavidw/node-csv-parse) library. The idea is to use the streaming API of the library and `unpipe` the parser from the file-stream after reading 10 records.

```js
var fs = require('fs');
var csv = require("csv-parse");
var i = 0;
var num = 10;


var stream = fs.createReadStream("test.csv");
var parser = csv();

function done() {
  stream.unpipe(parser);
  parser.end();
  stream.destroy();
}

parser.on('readable', function () {
  if (i < num) {
    var r = parser.read();
    console.log(i, r);
    i++;
  } else {
    done();
  }
});

parser.on('error', function() {console.log('Error');}); // TODO: Handle appropriately

parser.on('finish', done);
stream.pipe(parser);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.